# loop procedure mysql to make pair of row

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

I have some mysql problems here

I need make new table with pairs of row from source table,

`Source Table:
No     Name      Value
-----------------------
1       A1         20
2       A2         10
3       A3         40`

`New Table create:
No     Name     Pair   Value
----------------------------
1        A1      A1   (20,20)
2        A1      A2   (20,10)
3        A1      A3   (20,40) 
4        A2      A1   (10,20)
5        A2      A2   (10,10)
6        A2      A3   (10,40)
7        A3      A1   (40,10)
8        A3      A2   (40,20)
9        A3      A3   (40,40)`

Thanks hor help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cross join the table with itself, creating a Cartesian product, where each row is matched with each other row:

```
SELECT     a.itme AS item, 
           b.item AS pair,
           CONCAT('(', a.value, ',', b.value, ')') AS value
FROM       mytable a
CROSS JOIN mytable b
```

Comment: its works thanks Mureinik , Caputo